# Classes of frames in Modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

In Modal logic, a frame is defined as a pair (W,R), where W is a non-empty set (of possible worlds, states, or other terminology), and R is a binary relation on W.

However, what exactly is a 'class of frames'?
Is this just any random collection of frames? Or frames of a certain family/characteristic? Is there any official definition of 'a class of frames'? I couldn't find any, neither in the book, nor on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

See [Semantics of modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Semantics_of_modal_logic) :

> A Kripke frame or modal frame is a pair **⟨W,R⟩**, where **W** is a (possibly empty) set (the set of *worlds*), and **R** is a binary relation on **W** (the *accessibility relation*).

A *class of frames* is a collection of frames sharing some "relevant" property of the accessibility relation.

For example, if we "impose" the *frame condition* on **R** of *reflexivity*, we have that all the frames of the corresponding class satisfy the axiom

> **□A→A**.